# Selenium & Chrome: Differences between driver.browser.get() and manually typing the URL into the address bar and pressing enter

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am using:

- Python 3.8
- google chrome: Version 96.0.4664.93, 64 bit
- Selenium: 3.141.0

The context surrounding my issue is that there is a particular site that will load when I manually enter the URL into the Chrome address bar and press enter, but will not load if I use Selenium to execute a `get(URL)` request. I understand that manually entering the URL into the address bar and pressing enter also performs the same request and sends the same cookies/payload (From inspection of chrome debugger).

So my question is two-fold:

1. Are there any differences in the above methods to navigate to a URL?
2. Can a website detect somehow the difference between the two methods once the request has been made? e.g., perhaps by using javascript or another method on loading?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you check your request `headers` in two cases? Maybe, the website checks the `user-agent` or other headers to differentiate those two requests.
Also, Would you please add your targeted URL to check what's happening?

Comment: Yup, the headers were the same except for cookies that had different values as they were separate requests (but same keys).  A example URL would be any that point to a current listing on www.realestate.com.au

Comment: What is the exact difference between the 2 ways of opening the site? What is the exact result of doing it with selenium `driver.get(URL)` ?

Comment: @Prophet, I'll get a few more details later, but basically if entered manually into the address bar, the initial page loads, then some javascript is executed (isp.js from memory), then page loads normally. However, if the get() request is made, errors occur after the javascript is executed. I have a sneaky feeling it is to do with the cookies, even though they look the same.

But just to help me troubleshoot, I just wanted to know if there is anything different in mechanism between the two methods.